# let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} C^2$ s.t. $f' < 0$ and $\sup_x \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} < 2$ show that $f=o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

> #### Problem
>
> $$ \text{Let } f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ \text{be a }C^2 \text{ function}\text{ such that } \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} < 2 \text{ and } f'< 0  $$
>
> $$ \text{Show that } f(x) = o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty. $$

My attempt :

First let's notice the fact that $1-(\frac{f}{f'})' = \frac{ff''}{(f')^2}$
. We have using the first hypothesis :
$-(\frac{f}{f'})' \leq 1$ so by integrating we have $-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \leq x - \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$ and thus $f'(x) \leq f(x)\frac{1}{x - c}$ then by Gronwall lemma we get $f(x) \leq f(0)\frac{1}{c(c-x)}$ where $c = \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$ which proves the fact that $f = O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty.$
I can't find a way to have a better asymptotic result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $\gamma$ by the relation

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{\gamma}. $$

By the assumption, it is clear that $\gamma > 1$. Now using OP's idea, we get

$$ 1 - \left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)' = \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\gamma} $$

and hence we get $ - \left(\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\right)' \leq \frac{1}{\gamma} $.  Integrating both sides and setting $b = -\gamma \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)} > 0$, for $x \geq 0$ we get

$$ - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \leq \frac{x+b}{\gamma}, \qquad \text{or equivalently,} \qquad \frac{\gamma}{x+b} f(x) + f'(x) \leq 0. $$

We can tackle this with the method of integrating factors. Indeed, let $\mu(x) = (x + b)^{\gamma}$. Then by multiplying $\mu(x)$ to both sides of the last inequality, we get $ (\mu(x)f(x))' \leq 0 $ and hence

$$ \mu(x)f(x) \leq \mu(0)f(0) $$

for all $x \geq 0$. This shows that

$$ f(x) \leq \frac{C}{(x + b)^{\gamma}} $$

for $C = \mu(0)f(0) > 0$ and therefore $f(x) = o(1/x)$ as required.